# Create volume cube around object with equal padding from bounding box center?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, geometry, volumetrics, origin

I want to create a volume cube around an object with equal padding from the center of the bounding box of the object. Ideally, this would be a single value input (ie. "padding amount").

The issue(s) I'm having are:

1. Adjustments to the min/max values of the volume cube *appear* (to me) to be done from
   the origin of the object and not the center of the bounding box.
2. I can tweak min/max values to get the padding I want, but it is cumbersome and not intuitive because it involves 2 values and (⬆️see 1 above⬆️).

Basically, I just want the volume cube to be larger than the bounding box with an easy way to adjust how much.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

[image: Create volume cube around object with equal padding from bounding box center]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try scaling up ("inflate") the input geometry by its normal to get some padding:

[image]

Comment: I like the relative simplicity of this solution. Thank you! I also received an alternative solution on blender artists which I will include as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

I love the relative simplicity of the solution provided. It's worth noting I received [an alternative solution on Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org/t/create-volume-cube-around-object-with-equal-padding-from-bounding-box-center/1523188/2) which provides a more mathematical answer.

[image]